# What is the CURRENT_DATE or current date value function for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, date

What is the SQL Server functionality that allows you to get the current date as a `DATE` type like the SQL Standard's `CURRENT_DATE` feature. What is the `<current date value function>` for SQL Server?

Using PostgreSQL, I'm looking for something like,

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE;
 current_date 
--------------
 2018-06-27
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `CAST (... to date)` with `GETDATE()` or `SYSDATETIME()`

The best way is

```
SELECT CAST( GETDATE() AS date );
```

By extension in SQL Server, you can cast `SYSDATETIME()` to date,

```
SELECT CAST( SYSDATETIME() AS date );
```

The docs on [`SYSDATETIME` (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) show some more examples,

```
SELECT CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME())  
    ,CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())  
    ,CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME())  
    ,CONVERT (date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)  
    ,CONVERT (date, GETDATE())  
    ,CONVERT (date, GETUTCDATE());  

/* All returned 2007-04-30 */
```

There may be advantages `CAST (GETDATE() AS date)`, as `GETDATE()` natively returns less precision.

Comment: This is the way I have always done it, although if you are casting to DATE, does it matter if the input time has precision to the nanosecond?

Answer (score 9):

You can use either [`GETDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (return type [`datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) or [`SYSDATETIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (return type [`datetime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)), with the difference being the precision up to nanoseconds for `SYSDATETIME()`.

Example:

```
SELECT GETDATE() fn_GetDate, SYSDATETIME() fn_SysDateTime
```

Results:

```
fn_GetDate                 fn_SysDateTime
2018-06-27 10:31:18.963    2018-06-27 10:31:18.9659170
```

See [Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in the product documentation.

---

For completeness, SQL Server also recognises `CURRENT_DATE` as mentioned in the question, as an [ODBC scalar function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/odbc-scalar-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT {fn CURRENT_DATE()};
```

This returns `varchar(10)`, so would need an explicit cast or convert to the [`date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) data type:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, {fn CURRENT_DATE()});
```

The built-in functions are recommended over ODBC scalar functions.